# Running bat script from C#

Tags: c#, windows, process, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch script from within a c sharp program the code I am using is shown below:

```
 Process proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "G:\\Media\\Downloads\\print.bat";
 proc.Start();
```

The script is simple (for testing purposes) and contains one line:

```
echo hello > output.txt
```

When I run the script from windows explorer it works, but does not when run from the C# code.

any thoughts?

Also how can I give the processes a callback method for when it has finished?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify "doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes sorry, the script doesn't appear to be running as the file output.txt is not generated

Comment: The output.txt with the word "hello" is not in the "G:\Media\Downloads" folder?  Did you double check?

Comment: your file may be in bin\Debug folder

Comment: A trick I use as a diagnostic -- put this line in your command file: cd > c:\foo.txt   That will write the name of the current working directory to a file that you can examine.  Another tip: to change the cwd to the folder of the script, do this: cd /D "%~dp0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine for me. I'm guessing what's happening is that when you execute the batch file programmatically, you're expecting the output file to be created in the `Downloads` folder, when it's actually being created in the *application's* folder

Either fully qualify the output file-path in the batch file or change the working directory of the launched process, like this:

```
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"G:\Media\Downloads\";
```

As for your question about receiving notification when the process has finished, you can use the [**`WaitForExit`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method or the [**`Exited`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event on the `Process` object.