# How to execute an external script that is in notepad from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, external

I wrote a script in a notepad and saved it in a folder. Now I want to execute that script from c# button click.

Can you please help me how to do it?

Comment: What language is this script in?

Comment: Look out for System.Diagnostics.Process and ProcesstartINfo, start commandprompt and provide this script path.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have chosen the asp.net tag: Do you want to start the script on the server or on the client machines?
You can start the script with on the server, but starting scripts out from a browser is a different story:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\myscript.vbs");
```

Just make sure that you have the following line at the top of your file:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "G:\\Media\\Downloads\\print.bat";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"G:\Media\Downloads\";
proc.Start();
```

This answer is a combination of the question and answer from this  question: [Running bat script from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004946/running-bat-script-from-c-sharp)